# Parentheses around multiple fields at once in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

How can I add one pair of parentheses around multiple fields in a bibliography?

The standard authoryear format looks like this:

> > Leo Frobenius (1935). *Paideuma. Umrisse einer Kultur- und Seelenlehre*. Vol. 3. Some Series. Düsseldorf: Diederichs

My goal is:

> > Leo Frobenius (1935): *Paideuma. Umrisse einer Kultur- und Seelenlehre* (Some Series, Vol. 3). Düsseldorf: Diederichs

Replacing the dot with a colon is no problem.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Frobenius1935,
  title = {Paideuma. Umrisse einer Kultur- und Seelenlehre},
  publisher = {Diederichs},
  year = {1935},
  author = {Leo Frobenius},
  series = {Some Series},
  volume = {3},
  address = {Düsseldorf},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello Downvoter, please explain why as the OP is a new user ?. We are `TeX`.SX. I derive Patience from TeX. Don't scare new users.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. may be the Downvoters would be expecting you to do present your contribution of work on the biblatex example.

Comment: Small point: don't use `volume = 3` but `number = 3` for the third volume of a series. 'Volume' is used in relation to the (main) title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of the bibliography fields are declared for every bibliography driver by the command `DeclareBibliographyDriver{<eg. book>}`. For the example book I want to show a part of the code where volume + number + series are used:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  ....
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  ....
}
```

To setup parens around multiple fields you have to options:

1. redefinition of every bibliography driver
2. using the package [`regexpatch`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch) to patch the bibliography driver

Both options using the method that the input strings are executed inside the command `\printtext[parens]{...}` to get parens. In the MWE below I am using the second method:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Frobenius1935,
  title = {Paideuma. Umrisse einer Kultur- und Seelenlehre},
  publisher = {Diederichs},
  year = {1935},
  author = {Leo Frobenius},
  address = {Düsseldorf},
}
  series = {Some Series},
  volume = {3},
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}


\usepackage{regexpatch}
% Print ISSN
\xpatchbibdriver{book}
  {\iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  }%
  {%
  \ifboolexpr{%
      test {\iffieldundef{volume}} and 
      test {\iffieldundef{part}} and 
      test {\iffieldundef{series}} and
      test {\iffieldundef{number}} 
  }{}{%
   \printtext[parens]{%
     \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}%
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}}%
 }%
 }
  {\typeout{******WORKS******}}{\typeout{*******FAILS********}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: Why are you using `bibtex` instead of the advantages of `biber`?

Comment: Is it possible to omit the set of empty parentheses if there is a book without series and volume?

Comment: Sure? ;) I my opinion the boolean expr should be evaluated to true if all fields are undef

Comment: if one of the four fields is undef the true part will be executed cause of the or catenations. or am I wrong?

Comment: @user1494845: I am wrong ;-) -- I need `and`s -- To avoid extended comments I removed my.